# Ajax call to WebAPI - how to prevent spamming the submit button?

Tags: forms, web-services, api

I'd be interested to know how people have handled this problem.

I have a website with a single form (using divs to show/hide sections so it looks like three pages) and a submit button. The form is submitted via jQuery AJAX POST to my WebAPI method. I do not want people to be able to send the POST many times in quick submission.

I am disabling the Submit button on clicking it, but this does not prevent somebody writing a script in the console to call that method repeatedly. They can look at the javascript, see the URL, and POST to it.

I have heard about API keys but I don't think they apply here as there is no logging on to the website. And if there was, the key would still be required for repeat requests.

I could use a CAPTCHA I suppose... but what other options are available?

Answer (score 0):

The most useful thing would be use csrf tokens inside form. CSRF token will be update after each form submit.

You can easily prevent repeat requests.

Find more information here
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Please give some more detail, remembering this is an AJAX post. How does the server know the subsequent POSTs with the same token are to be ignored? Is there a WebAPI DataAnnotation to use?

Comment: @VictorySaber You have to change csrf value after first submission and regenerate new CSRF token. Here is one link which will give you idea how you can handle tokens. https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3454607

Comment: Assuming that is client-side, what is to stop somebody calling the token-generation method as well? e.g. getToken();postForm(token) in the console?